# Is this IPv6-link-local address (as reported by Windows) correct? If so, why?

Tags: windows, ipv6, link-local

From what I [read online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6), an IPv6 link-local address is generated by taking the network interface's MAC address, inserting an FF:FE word into the middle of it, OR'ing in some additional bits, et voila:  e.g. MAC address 00:3E:E1:c6:20:c2 corresponds to IPv6 link-local address fe80::23e:e1ff:fec6:20c2%en0, and a program that knows the MAC address can compute the IPv6 address, or vice-versa.

That seems to work fine on my Macintosh, but on my co-worker's Windows machine we see this (from ipconfig's output):

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::eb:b41:3e4c:fd9e%11
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Here it looks like the network interface's MAC address (which is 0b:41:3e:4c:fd:9e ) has had only the byte "eb" OR'd in to the front of it, rather than inserting ff:fe into the middle as I would have expected.

Can anyone explain why that is?  i.e. is Windows doing something contrary to the IPv6 link-local address specification here, or is it just using some other acceptable MAC->IPv6 convention that I'm unaware of?  Or perhaps vendors are just allowed to do whatever they want when generating an fe80 address from a MAC address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that a link-local address is required to be generated from the MAC address; it never has been a requirement. You can manually assign link-local addresses on many devices.

What you are seeing with Windows is the use of Privacy Extensions and random addressing. Instead of the original way of assigning a SLAAC Interface ID, Privacy Extensions and random address generation were introduced. This is the default for Windows, but it can be disabled.

See [RFC 4862, IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) and [RFC 4941, Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941).

Comment: And there is [RFC 7217, A Method for Generating Semantically Opaque Interface Identifiers with IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration (SLAAC)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7217), which allows for addresses that look random, will be stable, but different in every subnet, and are _not_ derived from the MAC address. (And perhaps [they will become](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-6man-default-iids-11) the standard for SLAAC.)

Comment: It would be quite a big chance that a randomly selected address would contain the bytes of the MAC address...